# Android ActionBarSherlock Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-support-library

I've been trying to get ActionBarSherlock working with Google's fragment tutorial and run into a problem when trying to add the "content" fragment to the view. This line produces the following exception

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, content).commit();

The method add(int, Fragment) in the type FragmentTransaction 
is not applicable for the arguments (int, ContentFragment)
```

The code is identical to Google's (http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) except I've extended to SherlockActivity where needed. ContentFragment/Activity is merely what I've called Details activity.

Even if I take out all of the ABS references to make it a normal example, I get the same problem. I have a feeling its to do with the android support library, but I cant for the life of me figure it out.

Comment: Are you using the Android Support Library? Because the ActionBarSherlock uses it. "import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;" The same goes for your ContentFragment (i.e extends android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;) 

see http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html

Comment: So should I be extending SherlockFragment or android.support.v4.app.Fragment? It seems more likely that I should be using sherlockfragment if that contains the support library but that's just my reasoning...

Comment: Hi!I think each of your fragments you should extend with android.support.v4.app.Fragment. But your activity containing these fragments should extend SherlockFragmentActivity. I did it this way i a project and It worked.

Comment: Solved it. getFragmentManager() in the question needed to be changed to getSupportFragmentManager(). App I can't answer my own question, so I'll leave this here for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`.

Answer (score 0):

How does your fragment class look like? This code works fine for me:

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    FragmentADetail frag = new FragmentADetail();
    ft.replace(android.R.id.content, frag);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
```

And my FragmentADetail class looks like this:

```
public class FragmentADetail extends SherlockFragment {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a_detail_layout, container, false);
    v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //left empty on purpose to capture the onClick event. 
        }
    });

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();
    getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
}
```

}

Comment: this is a good example but I think OP wants to add a fragment to a view. Not replacing it